# Is there any cost minimization algorithm for combining inverters in a solar power project?

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula

I work in a company that sells and install fotovoltaics.
Here we have a pricing table that goes from a project of 1 panel all the way to 200 panels.

For this pricing table we have a simple logic set up on a excel spreadsheet that makes a list of what inverters will be used on that project based on the number of panels and its power.

To simplify, these inverter are chosen based on the total power from the panels.
E.g. 5 panels of 500 watts = 2500 watts will require a single 2500 watts inverter.
Or, 100 panels of 500 watts = 50kW will require 5 inverters of 10000 watts each.

The excel spreadsheet we have today can already calculate the inverters required based on the number of panels and the panel power. But for that to happen the inverters we use have to be always the same, we cant add or remove inverters from the list.

If we change the inverters list the excel formulas break.
Also the way the spreadsheet calculate the inverters does not take into account the cost and just simply combine it based on a ascending order.

E.g. on a solar project composed of 24 panels of 500 watts we have 12000 watts of total panel power. We can make lots of different combinations of inverters. The ascending order of the spreadsheet will give us a 10000 watts inverter (which is our highest power inverter today) and another one of 2000 watts, totalizing the 12000. But this combination isnt the best for cost. A better combination would be 2 inverters of 6000 watts each. Considering a cost of $1949 for the 2kW inverter, a cost of $3899 for the 6kW inverter and $6179 for the 10kW inverter (these costs are the ones we have today)

[image: > List of inverters we use today]

> List of inverters we use today

[image: Example of the spreadsheet result, considering a 530 watts panel]

> Example of the spreadsheet result, considering a 530 watts panel

I don't understand much about programming and I'm just trying to find a solution to do this automatically, I would like to be able to set up a logic that optimize the inverter combination based on cost and also that I could add or remove any inverter from the list without having to change the formula.

Sorry for the long text but I tried to describe my problem in the best way. I am accepting any kind of help or guidance, where I could do this better apart from a excel spreadsheet, Even where I could get help about it. Thanks in advance to everyone who took the time to read this question.

Comment: I would set this up to use the Solver - inverter capacity ie kW must exceed pv capacity and cost must be a minimum. Can't have a go as your data is in picture form and I don't have time to type it out. However, I have done similar Solver solutions on here already so you can look for those.

Comment: Off topic comment here, but I am curious about the type of system. For my residential off-grid system with battery backup, I sized the inverters based on the maximum expected load.

Comment: This is typical `linear programming` with integer variables. Is there any use of `max power` column? Using price minimization, inverter grw 3.0min will never be picked in any combination. Is there any limit on supply of inverters?

Comment: @det Yes the 'max power' column will determine the maximum amount of panels that can be add to overload the inverter. But in this case i will only use the regular power. The inverter grw 3.0min is a special type so It will be removed from this example too thanks!
There are no limits for inverter supplies.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Our systems are on-grid only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't use excel and you are open to suggestions, I'll post R solution:

**required libraries**:

```
install.packages("tribble")
install.packages("lpSolve")

library(tribble)
library(lpSolve)
```

Installing packages is required to do only first time.

**data in a form of data.frame**:

```
inverters <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Inverter,     ~Power,    ~Cost,
  "GRW 1.5",     1500,      1809,
  "GRW 2.0",     2000,      1949,
  "GRW 2.5",     2500,      2049,
  "GRW 3.0 MIC", 3000,      2229,
  "GRW 5.0",     5000,      3549,
  "GRW 6.0",     6000,      3899,
  "GRW 8.0",     8000,      4869,
  "GRW 10",      10000,     6179
)
```

Columns of this `data.frame` are self explanatory. Adding new row will add new inverter, removing row will remove that inverter. Also updates of existing inverters require only value changes.

**minimum power value**

```
min_power <- 12000
```

`min_power` is power which we want to exceed with combination of inverters.

`inverters` and `min_power` are user inputs. Optimization process is based on those inputs and does not require any user changes.

**optimization**

```
res <- lpSolve::lp(
  direction = "min",
  objective.in = inverters$Cost,
  const.mat = matrix(inverters$Power, nrow = 1),
  const.dir = ">=",
  const.rhs = min_power,
  all.int = TRUE
)
```

**solution**

```
solution <- setNames(res$solution, inverters$Inverter)
solution <- solution[solution > 0]
solution_cost <- res$objval
```

For your example solution and its cost:

```
GRW 6.0 
      2 
7798
```

Comment: Thats more or less of how i imagined it would look like in code, but i am not familiarized with this programming language, what is that ?
Any idea on where i could implement this ?
And btw thanks for the answer this helps a lot!

Comment: watch videos how to install and run it, for example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFGYlKvQEQ4